# How import a project in another project in golang

Tags: go

I need to call multiple constants found in another go project, already run the command

```
go install
```

and create the executable but I don't know how to import it into the project where I need it

Comment: Please read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to read up on [go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) pretty extensively - they're used everywhere in the go environment nowadays, and a very important concept to grasp.

Once you feel comfortable with that, if this code you speak of is not in module form yet, you'll need to make it that way. After that, the constants you need will need to be exported (i.e capitalized variable names) like this:

```golang
package mymath

// unexported variable - local scope only
var pi = 3.14159265

// exported variable - global scope when in a module
var Pi = 3.14159265
```

Now, you can call `mymath.Pi` to get that constant value.

Answer (score -2):

go get project-github-or-smthelse-which-routes-to-source-code

Comment: But the code must already be in the git hub repository?